# .net website with mysql database

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I have a .net website hosted in IIS7.5 ON Windows 2008 R2. Application pool is .net V4.0 Integrated.
My web application is in .NET and the database is MYSQL.
My Connection String is:

> DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=mydb;UID=auser;PASSWORD=richard;OPTION=3

I have created a system DSN for mysql with above driver.

Application starts with a login page. When I enter username password, it returns null and hence the login fails. I tried running the stored procedure directly in the database and it returns results fine. The same application is running fine in development environment but fails after deployment in test.

When I deployed in test I had to remove following sections from my webconfig:

> `<section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
>    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
>   <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
>   <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
>     <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />`

due to this error: There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/webServices/roleService' section defined .

Any ideas how to resolve this will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

I have re-registered .NET WITH IIS

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

and also added in web.config but still same issue.

```
 <configuration>
<system.web>
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Have you dealt with membership and role providers?

Comment: I tested my DSN and it was successful.

Comment: I can see MySqlRoleProvider under providers in IIS

Comment: I *really* hope that connection string is just an example and not the real thing!

Comment: Yes it's an example and not the real db or username/pwd

Answer (score 0):

I just recently struggled getting ASP.net working with MySQL and the process to get it working was like this:

1. Download the MySql library from MySql and remember to add references and `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`
2. Download and create a local database through Mysql Workbench. You will be able to create an admin account, but to be able to connect to it with ASP, you will need to go into settings on your localhost and create a new user with same rights as the admin.
3. Setup an connection string like this: `const string MyConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=DbName;UID=userID;PWD=userPW;"`
4. Open connection like following:

> using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString))
>       {
>
> ```
>     using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
>     {
>         cmd.CommandText = xxxxxx; // Your query to the database
>         cmd.Connection = con;
>         cmd.Connection.Open();
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks Thommy. My application is working fine in development environment. It's only now when I deployed in test that I don't get any errors but the .net webapp is unable to retrieve information from mysql db. when I run storedproc in mysql editor it returns values but not the webapp so I am guessing there is some interface issue between both but i fail to find it.. Same application is running fine in dev environment with mysql db

Comment: Have you tried debugging and stepping through the process? You might connect and all that, but it fails during the actual "insert" process. Never done it in the way you are attempting, nor setup a test environment, so I lack knowledge with how the test environment differs from the development one.